# How does Spanish keep gender for 1st/2nd plural person possessive determiners, while dropping it elsewhere?

Tags: etimología, género, posesivos

In Spanish, the possessive determiners *nuestro* and *vuestro* have 4 forms, depending on gender and number. However, gender variation has disappeared in other determiners, *mi*, *tu* and *su* (number variations survived, as *mis*, *tus* and *sus*).

Comparing French which preserved the gender variation for singular persons, e.g. *mon* (m. sg.) and *ma* (f. sg.), while merged genders in the plural form (there's only one *mes*). Italian pretty well kept them all, offering *il mio*, *la mia*, *i miei* and *le mie*, and identical variations for *tuo*, *suo*, *nostro* and *vostro*.

The unified form for plural (gender-independent) in French, *mes*, appears like a result of a merge. But how did Spanish "merge" the genders of possessive determiners for singular persons (i.e. *mi*, *tu* and *su*), while keeping it for "nosotros" and "vosotros" versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mystery here.

- 1st person singular: the Latin forms *meus, mea* evolved somewhat irregularly to the Spanish emphatic forms *mío, mía* (it seems likely that there were for a while a competing form with an ascending diphthong: *mió*) and their plurals were formed regularly. When unstressed, as is the case always before a noun phrase, these forms lost their final vowels. This has been extremely common in Spanish historically.
- 2nd person singular: Latin *tuus* and *tua* gave old Spanish *tó, túa*, which apparently were reshaped by analogy with *cuyo* (from Latin *cuius*) for their emphatic forms: *tuyo, tuya*, with the insertion of a glide between the vowels in hiatus. The unstressed forms, as with the 1st person, lost their final vowels and finally settled on *tu*.

The 1st and 2nd person plural possessive pronouns, on the other hand, didn't undergo any analogical changes. They evolved regularly from the Latin forms *nostrum* and *vostrum* (plus their feminine forms in *-a*), giving *nuestro* and *vuestro*.